# Eclipse export jar different with ant jar

Tags: maven, ant, jar, size

I have a project with maven managed, now I had written a ant build.xml to export to a jar. The question is both maven and ant export as a jar is successful, but the size of them are different.I used the Folder Compare software to compare the content of the jars, I found that, the directory and structure of the jars is the same, but the file(*.class) size is different. There is anybody know why?
The size of maven jar is bigger then ant jar, I don't know why, help me, please! Thanks.

Comment: How do you compile your sources ? (I guess with maven-compiler-plugin when building with maven; but what about ant ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the title of your question, I guess that your ant build.xml will simply jar the .class compiled by eclipse. And that's why size are different.

Eclipse use it's own compiler to compile your sources (with a powerful incremental mode), while maven is using the standard javac compiler from the JDK.

That's why *.class file have different size (and indeed the byte code is not the same: it depends on the compiler you use to compile your sources).